# Bash script to convert videos in sub-directories

Tags: bash

Trying to make a script to convert videos within sub-directories while changing the filename, metadata, and dumping them all in a single folder for all converted videos. The `ffmpeg` command works on individual files while not using variables. The `cut` command changes the filename and metadata to what I want. I'm just having a hard time putting it all together.

```
find . -name "*.m2ts" -exec bash -c 'for f; do
    t=$(echo "$f" | cut -d "/" -f2)
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -af "volume=2.0" -f mp4 -c:a mp3 -c:v libx264 \
        -profile:v baseline -vf "scale=852:480" -metadata title="$t" $t.mp4; \
done' -- {} +
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an almost pure bash version of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.m2ts; do
    filename="${f/*\//}"
    ffmpeg -i "${filename}" \
        -af "volume=2.0" \
        -f mp4 \
        -c:a mp3 \
        -c:v libx264 \
        -profile:v baseline \
        -vf "scale=852:480" \
        -metadata title="${filename/.*/}" \
        ${filename/.m2ts/.mp4}
 done
```

Can you give it a try?

BTW, here is some Bash Fu:

```
$ f="./some/file.m2ts"
$ echo ${f}
./some/file.m2ts
$ echo ${f/*\//}
file.m2ts
$ filename=${f/*\//}
$ echo ${filename}
file.m2ts
$ echo ${filename/.*/}
file
$ echo ${filename/.m2ts/.mp4}
file.mp4
$
```

Comment: Thank you, I just had to make a few changes to account for recursive sub-directories and issues with spaces in filenames.

Comment: No worries. I'm glad it helped.